# Caret feature selection with customized random forest classifier

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, caret

I'm following the Caret package tutorial for constructing customized functions for a [recursive feature elimination](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html). I can reproduce the provided example which is a random forest regression. However, when I modify the code to deal with classification, I receive an odd error:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(Hmisc)
library(randomForest)

n <- 100
p <- 40
sigma <- 1
set.seed(1)
sim <- mlbench.friedman1(n, sd = sigma)
colnames(sim$x) <- c(paste("real", 1:5, sep = ""),
                         paste("bogus", 1:5, sep = ""))
    bogus <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
    colnames(bogus) <- paste("bogus", 5+(1:ncol(bogus)), sep = "")
    x <- cbind(sim$x, bogus)
y <- sim$y
#customizing tutorial example for binary outcome

y[y <= 12] <- 0    
y[y> 12] <- 1

y <- factor(y)


normalization <- preProcess(x)
x <- predict(normalization, x)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
subsets <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
rfRFE <-  list(summary = defaultSummary,
                      fit = function(x, y, first, last, ...){
             library(randomForest)
             randomForest(x, y, importance = first, ...)
             },
           pred = function(object, x)  predict(object, x),
           rank = function(object, x, y) {
             vimp <- varImp(object)
             vimp <- vimp[order(vimp$Overall,decreasing = TRUE),,drop = FALSE]
                 vimp$var <- rownames(vimp)
             vimp
             },
           selectSize = pickSizeBest,
           selectVar = pickVars)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs,
                   method = "repeatedcv",
                   repeats = 5,
                   verbose = FALSE)
ctrl$functions <- rfRFE
    ctrl$returnResamp <- "all"
set.seed(10)
rfProfile <- rfe(x, y, sizes = subsets, rfeControl = ctrl)
rfProfile
```

The error is:

```
Error in {: task 1 failed - "argument 1 is not a vector"
```

My question is how should one go about defining `rfRFE` for random forest models with binary response variables?

Comment: You're missing some code--you never define your **ctrl** variable.

Comment: Another issue: `y[y <= 12] <- 0` needs to come before `y[y> 12] <- 1` or else you end up with a vector of all zeros.

Comment: I corrected the typos that I had while copy/pasting from my console. The error and question remain the same.

Comment: Also, it is a really good idea to use class levels that are valid R names. Try that and see if you still get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the response variable is a factor with level names starting with a letter